# Xamarin Form: Using symbols as Text on button?

Tags: layout, xamarin, keyboard, special-characters

I am creating a customised keyboard on xamarin form using plainly buttons. The cap/backspack,enter key using symbol of text to display not in image.
Symbols = ⇧ ⇪ ⌫ .

The reason not using image to represent them is mainly resizing required to adjust them to have the same size with other buttons of alphabet. If I used text to represent, the sizing can easily control with other buttons by using textSize.

One question: if I used those three symbols, will it compatible with all devices?

Answer (score 1):

> I used those three symbols, will it compatible with all devices?

The different platforms may render these glyphs differently, but they all mean same thing

I am using these symbols in an iOS keyboard, they all look same on iPhone and iPod
https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/ios8/KannadaKeyboard/